# d3.js creating grid-styled bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to dynamically build some "money bar charts" like in this example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVRRo.jpg

I have the algorithm to determine how many bills need to be generated for each category. the little dollar signs have already been created in svg. So really all I have to do is append them in a grid like fashion.
Then, I have to be able to create multiple bar charts based on the number of different categories present in the data set.

Really at this point, its just creating the dollar signs around the "grid" format that I am stuck. Any help would be great.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Great, sounds like you're making good progress.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how I could create the bar graphs around the "grid"? When there are dollar signs they are populated in the order from top left then down and then back to top of second row.

Comment: Well you could use `d3.range()` to generate one item up to a number and then use that as the data to add images.

Comment: Showing use some code would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example.  I've commented it out, let me know what you don't understand.  I am cheating a bit and drawing the bills with a `rect` element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
    var data = [{
      "name": "Web", "value": 376.19
    },{
      "name": "Phone", "value": 550.55
    },{
      "name": "Store", "value": 125.25
    }]
    
    // some constants
    var billWorth = 20, // bill value
        billWidth = 50,
        billHeight = 26,
        numRows = 4
        sectionSpace = 150; // space allocated for each group of data
    
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", 600)
      .attr("height", 600)
      .append("g");
    
    // a group for data point
    var g = svg.selectAll("finance")
      .data(data, function(d){
        return d.name;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "finance");
    
    // the name of each group
    g.append("text")
      .text(function(d){
        return d.name;
      })
      .style("fill","black")
      .attr("transform",function(d,i){
        return "translate(10,"+ ((i * sectionSpace) + (sectionSpace/2)) +")"
      })
    
        // a group for collection of bills
        // this is a subselection of the finance group
    var bill = g.append("g")
      .attr("transform",function(d,i){
        return "translate(70,"+ ((i * sectionSpace) + 10) +")"
      })
      .selectAll("bill")
      // our data is the range of the number of bills 
      .data(function(d){
        // store this in the data so I can use it later
        d.numBills = Math.ceil(d.value / billWorth);
        return d3.range(d.numBills);
      })
      .enter()
          // a group for each bill
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "bill")
      // position each bill
      .attr("transform",function(d,i,j){
        var trans = "";
        var x = Math.floor(d / numRows) * (billWidth + 5); // this is the column
        var y = ((d % numRows) * (billHeight + 5)); // this is the row
        trans += "translate("  + x + "," + y + ")";
        return trans;
      })
    
    // draw the bill
    bill
      .append("rect")
      // on the last bill, shorten it to represent a partial value
      .attr("width", function(d,i,j){
        if (d === data[j].numBills - 1){
          return billWidth * ((data[j].value % billWorth) / billWorth);
        } else {
          return billWidth;
        }
      })
      .attr("height", billHeight)
      .style("stroke","green")
      .style("fill","green");

    bill
      .append("text")
      .text("$")
      .style("fill","white")
      .attr("x", billWidth / 2.3)
      .attr("y", billHeight / 1.5);
   
   </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: oh ma god @Mark, thanks so much for this example! The general structure of your code is what I had in mind, but seeing it really makes it clear. I will use your general idea for my code. Again thanks x100. This is truly appreciated!